# Calculate a color with opacity based on it's values over other colors?

Tags: colors, opacity, linear-algebra, alphablending, alpha-transparency

For example, I know the color is #a0c5e8 (160,197,232) when over white, and it's #496e91 (73,110,145) when over black.

Is there a way to calculate the "real" color (at 100% opacity)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, by solving a system of linear equations. Let's look at the red channel as an example:

Variables:
*c* - color (unknown)
*f* - opacity (unknown)

Equations:
*c* * *f* + (1 − *f*) * 255 = 160. (blending with white)
*c* * *f* + (1 − *f*) * 0 = 73. (blending with black)

Rearrange to get:
*c* * *f* − 255 *f* = −95.
*c* * *f* = 73.
255 *f* = 168.

Therefore:
*f* = 168/255 ≈ 65.9%.
*c* = 6205/56 ≈ 110.8.

Computing the other channels, your final color is (111,167,220) and opacity is 66%.

Comment: Perfect! Math checks out, and so does the visual test!  Final color is rgba(111, 167, 220, 0.659)

Comment: I'm trying to use this equation for something I'm working on. But I cannot for the life of me work out how you got 6205 & 56?

Comment: @milky_jay Once you set up the equations, you can run them through any standard linear system solver. It's high school linear algebra.